# how to copy data from one sheet to other sheet with some criteria on column of sheet one. Data should be pasted on last row of sheet 2 every time

Tags: vba, excel

I have my data in worksheet 1 with Row headers..Like Name, City, Assignment,Date. Now worksheet 1 is having list of 100 members in Column1 and they will be assigned 2-3 type of assignment on daily basis. Assignment will be entered on Column 2..Date will will entered into Column 3.

I want to copy assignment for every date mentioned in Worksheet 1 to Worksheet. As this is for record so i want to paste data in new line of worksheet 2 so that previous record may maintain.

All these activity should be performed if any condition is matching in coloumn B

Action will be performed with any command button..

I have below code which is working to copay all the data range from sheet(new) to Sheet(Data) but here i want to copay data on condition...

...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()
'Find the last used row in a sheet and copy and paste data below it.

Dim lRow As Long

    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    '1. Find last used row in destination sheet
    lRow = Worksheets("Data").Cells(Worksheets("Data").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Offset 1 row below last used row
    lRow = lRow + 1

    '2. Copy data
    Worksheets("New").Range("A2:C4").Copy

    '3. Paste data
    Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & lRow).PasteSpecial

    'Clear copy mode (marching ants around copied range)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: So why isn't your code working? It's tough to follow your question.

Comment: Its working...i am giving you excel file..

Comment: Please take excel file..run the macro..its working.

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/ewp7ors34i2krjk/Copy_from_one_cell_to_other.xlsm